# Graphic is CC licensed on one site, but not on another

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

I found a vector graphic I want to use on a site *A* that offers free graphics under the Creative Commons License. Later I found that same graphic on a different (paid) site *B*, under their standard license (which does not allow distribution).

I assume there are two possibilities:

1. Site *A* bought it from site *B* and put it under CC license
2. Site *B* downloaded it from site *A* and put it up for sale on their site

In either case, can I safely download and use it from site *A*?  Or is it my responsibility to always try to determine if something has a different license somewhere else?

Comment: Where are you located? Copyright may be slightly different.

Comment: Living in germany.

Answer (score 1):

Case 2 is clearcut: assuming that site *A* is the author of the artwork, or is the site where the author first published, you've got a clear right to use the work under the given Creative Commons license.

Case 1 is more difficult: transfer of a copy of a work does not, in general, transfer the copyright as well.  Unless site *A* purchased or otherwise obtained the rights to re-license the work, their Creative Commons license statement is invalid.

Comment: Case #1 could result in "innocent infringement" liability for anyone reliant on *A*'s claim to be able to license it.

Comment: While I understand that in Case 1 Site _A_ probably doesn’t have the right to license the work, can i be held responsible for using it from them? I guess that’s what "innocent infringement“ means @feetwet?